# Web servers that support Mutual SSL and FastCGI

Tags: web-applications, ssl, ssl-certificate

Do you know any web servers that support both [Mutual SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication) and FastCGI?

I would like to establish a secure connection using the web server software and then route the request via a FastCGI socket (on the same machine of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Httpd](http://httpd.apache.org/) supports both.

See:

- http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/HelpOnInstalling/FastCgi
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html